# Go with tcpdump as external command: how to close external command properly?

Tags: go

I have a Go function to capture network traffic with **tcpdumb** (external command) on macOS:

```
func start_tcpdump() {
    // Run tcpdump with parameters
    cmd := exec.Command("tcpdump", "-I", "-i", "en1", "-w", "capture.pcap")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    timer := time.AfterFunc(3 * time.Second, func() {
        cmd.Process.Kill()
    })
    err := cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    timer.Stop()
}
```

When this function complete work, I'm trying to open output .pcap file in Wireshark and getting this error:
"**The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet.**"
Probably, *cmd.Process.Kill()* interrupts correct closing of .pcap-file.

What solution could be applied for "proper" closing of tcpdumb external process?

Comment: tcpdump says it exits normally via SIGINT or SIGTERM. Maybe read stdout and stderr to see if there are any relevant messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `cmd.Process.signal(os.Interrupt)` to signal tcpdump to exit, `Kill()` internally calls `signal(Kill)` which is equivalent to `kill -9` to force the process to exit.

Comment: Ah yes, the default posix kill signal is TERM, but here kill really is SIGKILL.